# Need to stop the api execution once i receive certain status i response in jmeter

Tags: while-loop, jmeter, controller

For the ride bookin app i need to stop the execution of 'End Ride' api once i receive the status as 'COMPLETED' in response.Currently I am using while controller but that enters infinite loop.
API Response:
{"id":3820,"status":"COMPLETED","rider":{"id":2019,"firstname":"test","lastname":"rider","phoneNumber":"9000000124","email":"Test_rider_10002@popp1.com","rating":5.0,"user":{},"fullName":"test rider"},"startLocationLat":36.10805389068134,"startLocationLong":-115.16570490025539,"endLocationLat":36.10805389068134,"endLocationLong":-115.16570490025539,"startAddress":"73 South Martin Luther King Boulevard","endAddress":"920 West Bonanza Road","start":{"address":"73 South Martin Luther King Boulevard","zipCode":"89106"},"end":{"address":"920 West Bonanza Road"},"surgeFactor":1.00,"driverPayment":"4.00","requestedCarType":{"title":"STANDARD","carCategory":"REGULAR","plainIconUrl":"https://media.ride-vegas.com/regular.png","configuration":"{"skipRideAuthorization": false}"},"requestedDriverTypes":[],"freeCreditCharged":"0.00"}

This is the JSON and it is validated correctly over https://jsonlint.com/. I need to execute the END RIDE API only once when the status is COMPLETED .Is there any way wherein i can do so?

While controller:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def apiDetails = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(current.getResponseData())
def eventStatus=apiDetails.status
def shouldRun = "1"

if(eventStatus =="COMPLETED") {
  shouldRun = "0"
}
vars.put("shouldRun", shouldRun+"")
log.info("shouldRun: " + vars.get("shouldRun"));

While condition:
${__jexl3("${shouldRun}" != "0" && ${__jm__While Controller__idx} < 2,)}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your API response is not a valid JSON (you can check it yourself using [JSON Linter](https://jsonlint.com/)), if this is the case and not a copy-paste issue - you won't be able to use [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
2. I don't know what `current` is, if you're using the Groovy code in a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) somewhere inside the While Controller you need to replace `current` with `prev` which stands for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html). See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands
3. `def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();` - this line can be removed as it doesn't do anything at all

Comment: I have updated the JSON in the question.I need to know how can i execute the api only once when the status is completed .